# Javascript misfunction with checked box on internet explorer 6

Tags: javascript, checkbox, internet-explorer-6

i've this script that is supposed to check a list of checkbox:

```
function onchangeSelectAllAnalysable() {
    var selectAll = document.forms[0].selectAllAnalysable;
    var selectedItems = document.forms[0].selectedItemsAnalysable;

    if(selectedItems != undefined) {
        if(selectedItems.length != undefined) {
            for (var i=0; i<selectedItems.length; i++) {
                selectedItems[i].checked = selectAll.checked;
            }
        } else {
            selectedItems.checked = selectAll.checked;
        }
    }
    toggleShuntDiscardButtons();
}
```

On FF Chrome and IE7/8/9 it works fine but i need it on IE6.
Now when i activate the script i've seen that it gos thru every single box
and check it but at the end when they are all checked they get unchecked again.

It seems strange even because, after that script nothing is executed...

Thx
Daniele

Comment: Can you provie more code? I don't know the code of 'toggleShuntDiscardButtons();' and what does it mean '.selectAllAnalysable' ? Is it an attribute, a name oder a css class?

Comment: selectAllAnalysable is another checkbox that activate the script itself, toggleShuntDiscardButtons is just i function thet enable some buttons, i've tried to put an alert after the 'toggleShuntDiscardButtons()' and i've seen that while the alert is open all the checkbox ar checked, but when i press 'ok' the alert disappear and all the checkbox get unchecked again

Comment: Can you post the full html code? You can use also http://fiddle.net and post the link here. I'm unable to make your code work, at my test file.

Comment: I don't understand this code: what is selectedItems? Is it an array of checkboxes, or a checkbox? According to the code, if it has a length property, then toggle each of its checked values -- otherwise, set its checked value.

Answer (score 0):

Because you haven't posted relevant source code, I added my working base. After a couple of changes my code work also with IE6.

The code:

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript">
function onchangeSelectAllAnalysable()
{
    var selectAll = document.forms[0].elements["selectAllAnalysable"];
    var selectedItems = document.forms[0].elements["selectedItemsAnalysable"];

    if (typeof (selectedItems) == "object")
    {
        if(selectedItems.length != 0)
        {
            for (var i=0; i<selectedItems.length; i++) {
                selectedItems[i].checked = selectAll.checked;
            }
        } else {
            selectedItems.checked = selectAll.checked;
        }
    }
    toggleShuntDiscardButtons();
}
function toggleShuntDiscardButtons(){/*whatever you do here*/}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<form name="x" action="http://www.stackoverflow.com" method="post">
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItemsAnalysable"><br>
<input type="checkbox" name="selectedItemsAnalysable"><br>
<p><input type="checkbox" name="selectAllAnalysable" onClick="onchangeSelectAllAnalysable()"></p>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Attention! IE6 don't accept the event '`onChange`' for radiobuttons and checkboxen. You have to use '`onClick`' instead.

As you wrote, the checkboxes will be rechecked and you haven't provide the code for the function *toggleShuntDiscardButtons()*, you should checked the code there. Maybe you forgott some code to remove.